# Do I have to re-join the whole data set even if only one property in one item changed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a relatively big data set (say 10000+ items).
I have bound this data to a D3 selection to generate item visuals.

If I have only one simple property changed in one item in this data set, I have to re-join the whole same data set to the selection again.

```
container.selectAll(".item").data(dataset);
```

Is there any api in D3 can handle this simple change instead of re-join the whole same data set to it?

Comment: You just need to change the bound datum object in that item, nothing more.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I did the change in the item, but nothing changes in UI. Say I have changed one item's property 'checked' from 'false' to 'true', but the related UI won't change until I re-join the whole data set.

Comment: Changing a property and updating an selection are two distinct things. You don't need to re-join the data, but you do need to update the selection.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, that's my question. How can I do updating the selection other than "container.selectAll(".item").data(dataset);"

Comment: I wrote an answer, but just for your information, `container.selectAll(".item").data(dataset);` does not update the selection, it simply re-binds the data. Nothing in the visualisation will change (unless you actually update the selection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

You don't have to re-join the whole dataset, specially if you have a huge data array and just one object has changed.

You can change the data array itself or change the datum in the D3 selection, it doesn't matter... what does matter is that changing the datum alone (using any of these methods) do not change the datavis, be it a SVG, a canvas or even a pure HTML datavis. For that, you need to update selection.

Here is a very simple demo, we have a huge array of 500 objects:

```
const data = d3.range(500).map(function(d) {return {prop: true}});
```

And, using that array, we build a set of divs.

Suppose that we change a single object:

```
data[100].prop = false;
```

The data has changed, but for the visualisation to change we have to change the selection (which is `divs` in the code). In the demo, the selection is updated after 1 second, the 100th div will turn red:

```js
const data = d3.range(500).map(function(d) {
  return {
    prop: true
  }
});
const body = d3.select("body");
const divs = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", "white");
  
 divs.transition()
  .delay(function(_, i) {
    return i
  })
  .style("background-color", function(d) {
    return d.prop ? "green" : "red"
  })

data[100].prop = false;

d3.timeout(function() {
  divs.style("background-color", function(d) {
    return d.prop ? "green" : "red"
  });
}, 1000)
```

```css
div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```